# How to raise mouse events from code behind in different positions of screen?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

How to raise mouse button events from code behind when we have only mouse position?
I need to raise mouse events from code behind in different positions of screen.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I need to create panel which would have properties like iPod kinetic scroll panel. And when it has content (buttons, radiobuttons, ...) I have problems with catching such events as MouseLeftButtonDown, MouseMove and MouseLeftButtonUp becouse content of panel catches them. And I need to catch them after some delay after MouseLeftButtonDown to understand if user wants to press content or to move it.
Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: @bgodiy:  Significant new information should be added to your question rather than languish as a mere comment to your question, note the edit link under your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm.. quite simply no you can't.

**Edit**

Now that you've describe what it is you actually need to do (a useful techinque in getting your problems solved).  Here is the solution:-

Use the `AddHandler` method to attach a handler for the MouseLeftButtonDown and the MouseLeftButtonUp.

```
myPanel.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown, MyButtonDown_Handler, true);
```

Note the final `true` parameter is the enabler here, it indicates that your handler should be called even if another element has indicated that the event has been handled.

Whilst you cannot add a handler for `MouseMove` in this way that is not a problem since `MouseMove` cannot be marked as handled anyway, so you just attach a handler to the Panel for `MouseMove` in the normal manner.

Comment: Maybe you can suggest some other solution of my problem?